# How to write the SLOBODA trend function in R

Tags: r, regression

What is the R code for the following formula?

[image]

Comment: What part of this formula is a riddle to you? This looks like very very basic stuff.

Answer (score 2):

```
H = b*(S/b)*exp(-b/((a-1)*50^(a-1)) + b/((a-1)*t^(a-1)))
```

provided `b`, `S`, `a`, `t` are all defined previously.